# &gt; in HTML is not displaying the closing bracket ">"

Tags: html, text

There are two problems here: The < / a > is not displaying correctly and the last line is remaining blue when it should be black. I am trying to convert the entire code for a link element to show in HTML in its text form.

```
<body>
<p>Where is the closing bracket? <br> 
<font color=blue> &lt;a ID=one-link href=http://CNN.com>CNN</a &gt; </font> or<br>
&lt;a class=many-links href=http://CNN.com>CNN</a&gt; </font><br>
and why is this line also blue?
```

Here is the link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajet8np7/1/).

Looking at the coloring in JSfiddle, looks like it is lumping the &gt code with font and the  as well.

Also, while at it, I'm also trying to figure out why the last line has blue text as well when I closed off the blue font specification. I think if I solve the first problem this would resolve as well.

Comment: Remember that you should also replace `<`, not only `>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<body>
<p>Where is the closing bracket? <br> 
<span style="color:blue"> &lt;a ID=one-link href=http://CNN.com&gt;CNN&lt;/a&gt; </span> or
<br />
&lt;a class=many-links href=http://CNN.com&gt;CNN&lt;/a&gt; </span>
<br />
and why is this line also blue?
```

You forgot to replace `<` by `&lt;`

Comment: Thanks! Just never occurred to me that all instances of brackets wouldn't naturally be printed out.

Answer (score 0):

you've included `<font color="blue">` in your html, thats why it shows blue, moreover `<font>` tag is depreciated in html5, so remove that, update your html with the below

**HTML**

```
<p>Where is the closing bracket? <br> 

&lt;a ID="one-link" href="http://CNN.com">CNN</a &gt;  or<br>
&lt;a class="many-links" href="http://CNN.com">CNN</a&gt; <br>

and why is this line also blue?
</p>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ajet8np7/2/)